# How to identify outliers in a column data about test scores and return country names for outliers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers

~What I've done~

In the first part of this assignment, I had to take data (from here: [a link] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programme_for_International_Student_Assessment_(2000_to_2012) ) about math, science, and reading scores and put them in three separate charts with country name and score.

Then I had to combine the charts by country name and find the average of the three scores. Then I had to rank them and put them in order by rank.

~What I need to do~

Next, I need to create a function to find the outliers (greater than 1.8 times the standard deviation) for different column string headers (average, math score, science score, and reading score), find the outlier in those scores, and print the country for the outliers under that header. I need to pass through a string (Average, Math Score, Science Score, Reading Score) and get a list of country names.

I tried to adapt a previous assignment in which we had to locate outliers in one set of data and ~remove~ them from the data. That one had a lot of math for finding mean and standard deviation, so I tried to simplify it here. In this one I just need to find out where the outliers occur.

tempDF is the temporary dataframe made using the combined charts.

[tempDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ADoR.png)

```
   def find_outlier(str):
         outliers = []
         found = True
         while found:

             for i in range(len(str)):   

                 mean = (tempDF[str].mean())
                 std = (tempDF[str].std())
                 distance = abs((str[i]-mean)/std)

                 if distance > 1.8:             
                     outliers = outliers.append()   
                     print("The outliers in ", str, " are ", outliers)

                     found=True
                     break
                 found = False

      find_outlier("Average")
      find_outlier("Math Score")
      find_outlier("Science Score")
      find_outlier("Reading Score")
```

It should print "The outliers in Average are ['China Shanghai, China,', 'Qatar', 'Peru']" etc. for each category (Average, Math, Science, Reading).

The error I'm getting now is "TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type". What I'm guessing is that the numbers in the columns might be strings and not numbers.

Comment: Please share `tempDF` content.

Comment: Here you appending nothing: `outliers.append()`

Comment: You're iterating over Title string here: `for i in range(len(str)):`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I need to pass the contents of a string column title in tempDF (for example, Average) and process the numbers in the specified column. So there I'm trying to run through the entire length of the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
tempDF = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['A']*1000+['B'], 'Income' : [10]*1000+[1000]})

def find_outlier(df, col):
    return df[abs((df[col]-df[col].mean())/df[col].std())>1.8]['country'].values
    # OR
    #return df[np.abs((df[col]-np.mean(df[col]))/np.std(df[col]))>1.8]['country'].values

print ("The outliers in {0} are {1}".format("Income", find_outlier(tempDF, "Income")))
```

Output:

```
The outliers in Income are ['B']
```